# Why does nuclear fission release energy if individual nucleons are heavier?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, mass-energy

You need to supply energy to separate nucleus, so if the nucleus was separated, shouldn't it have more energy(heavier)? If so, there won't have mass defect and will not release energy either.

I am confused, thank you.

Comment: There's a big difference in the fission process and the total dissociation of the nucleus into individual nucleons. For $^{235}U$ fission, you only need an extra neutron to get enough energy for fission. $^{236}U$ mass is quite a bit less than $^{235}U+n$. The fission products have much larger binding energies.

Answer (score 1):

After fission, the nucleons aren't necessarily heavier. The energy input is simply to get the fission raction 'going'. The energy output from the fission itself is many times larger than the energy input (see figure).

[image]

The initial bump upwards you see is the energy put into the system. The $\Delta E$ is the energy gained.

Figure from: http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/pshapley/GenChem1/L7/1.html

Comment: You should cite the source of the figure.

Comment: You're right, and I forgot! I edited my answer to include a reference.

Comment: Its first time ive seen such a graph in about 5 or so years,.  I question I always had is whether or not that reaction can use a catalyst to reduce the Ea a bit?  Or is fission a process that is not catalyst compatible?

Comment: Actually, the addition of a neutron with nearly zero KE  to 235-U provides enough energy to overcome the $E_a$ fission barrier for that system.  See the answers by @annav and John Rennie at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29555/how-to-measure-activation-energy-of-fission

Answer (score 1):

To “make” a nucleus you bring together a number of nucleons (protons and neutrons) and in the process energy is released.
The total mass of the individual nucleons is greater than the mass of the nucleus and the difference is called the mass defect $\Delta m$.
The energy released during the manufacture of the nucleus from the constituent nucleons is called the binding energy which is equal to $\Delta m c^2$ where $c$ is the speed of light.
So one can think that during the formation of the nucleus some mass is converted into energy.

Is you want to break up a nucleus into its constituent parts some energy must be added (equal to the binding energy of the nucleus) and mass of the resulting individual nucleons is now greater than the mass of the nucleus.
So you can think of the energy which has been added being converted into the extra mass (the mass defect).